# Why is this permissions error occurring with mod_passenger.so?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

I'm setting up a production RHEL 6 server with RVM and Passenger. I've gotten through installing RVM (to my home dir), installing Passenger, and adding the required lines to `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/em/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/ruby
```

But when I restart Apache I get this error...

```
$ sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 218 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /home/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Experimentally, I set the whole path starting at `~/.rvm/...` to 777, but I'm still getting that same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: it looks more like the passenger module has issues loading something: `/home/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_production/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied`, please verify with passenger docs you have all required modules loaded before passenger

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out to have to do with SELinux.

The Passenger docs discuss it [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_the_apache_error_log_says_that_the_spawn_manager_script_does_not_exist_or_that_it_does_not_have_permission_to_execute_it).

After you install Passenger, find the Passenger root...

```
passenger-config --root
```

Then run this...

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /path-to-passenger-root
```

Comment: This got me a little further, but still things weren't working - ended up following this [guide](http://sergiy.kyrylkov.name/2012/02/26/phusion-passenger-with-apache-on-rhel-6-centos-6-sl-6-with-selinux/).  This creates a policy based on what things passenger/apache actually need to run.

Comment: Didn't work for me on CentOS 6.5, where a user has installed passenger from gem and this user manages the Apache config. Disabling SELinux as in @okliv's answer works, so it's still a similar SELinux issue.

Answer (score 16):

`$ sudo setenforce 0`

helped me

hope it help others!

**UPDATE**

i have to say that above solution is temporal (until reboot)

so, as far as this answer has popularity let me show how to disable SELinux at all...

here it is:

run

```
$ sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

or

```
$ sudo vi /etc/selinux/config
```

then find this line

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

and change it to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

save selinux config.

now SELinux is fully disabled.

cheers

Comment: If you want to turn off selinux, I've always been a fan of using SELINUX=permissive because it will print warnings instead of making things not work.