# Installing gitorious on Centos 5.8 (Passenger module)

Tags: ruby, apache, centos, centos5, gitorious

I am trying to install gitorious on a Centos 5.8 box following this tutorial: http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Rhel_Installation, but right after I install Passenger and add the suggested lines:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11  
PassengerRuby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/ruby
```

to my httpd.conf, apache is unable to start.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Iniciando httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 200 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
                                                       [FALLÃ]
```

I have allready tried chmod -R 777 /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/ and still get this error.

Any help will be appreciated!!! Thanks in advance guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it didn't have anything to do with gitorious, but with the passenger module instead, the answer was here all along: [Why is this permissions error occurring with mod_passenger.so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337706/why-is-this-permissions-error-occurring-with-mod-passenger-so)

This is what I ran to get apache to start:

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/
```

No errors! Thats whats up!

This is the first time I work with rails so it got me for a newbie.

Hope this helps!