# Apache, Centos, Passenger issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, centos6

Environment:

- Centos 6.5
- 64bit
- Apache 2.2.15
- ruby 1.9.3p484
- passenger (4.0.37)

I continue to get 500 Server Error from Apache and cannot get it display anything passenger/rails. I've been able to get to and move around the app with webrick so I'm confident the issue isn't the actual app itself.

output from /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[ pid=10486, timestamp=1394054675 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4, randomSeed=1394054282
[ pid=10486 ] Crash log dumped to /var/tmp/passenger-crash-log.1394054675
[ pid=10486 ] Date, uname and ulimits:
Wed Mar  5 16:24:35 EST 2014
Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 00:41:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 14567
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14567
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[ pid=10486 ] Phusion Passenger version: 4.0.37
[ pid=10486 ] libc backtrace available!
--------------------------------------
[ pid=10486 ] Backtrace with 32 frames:
Using backtrace sanitizer.
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::dumpBacktrace(Passenger::AbortHandlerState&, void*) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/agents/Base.cpp:553) [0x5b6fc3]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::runInSubprocessWithTimeLimit(Passenger::AbortHandlerState&, void (*)(Passenger::AbortHandlerState&, void*), void*, int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/agents/Base.cpp:396) [0x5b68e5]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::dumpDiagnostics(Passenger::AbortHandlerState&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/agents/Base.cpp:742) [0x5b7a47]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::abortHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/agents/Base.cpp:987) [0x5b8596]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(?? at ??:0; +0xf710) [0x7fac7a750710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(?? at ??:0; readdir+0x29) [0x7fac79aada79]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::DebugDir::readAll() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Spawner.h:260) [0x4c30e4]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::annotatePreloaderException(Passenger::SpawnException&, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::DebugDir> const&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/SmartSpawner.h:197) [0x4cb510]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/SmartSpawner.h:514) [0x4ce8f7]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/SmartSpawner.h:592) [0x4cf2bd]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/SmartSpawner.h:278) [0x4cc25a]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options const&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/SmartSpawner.h:756) [0x4d1427]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner> const&, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options const&, unsigned int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.cpp:810) [0x593fc2]
PassengerHelperAgent(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadMain(boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.cpp:765) [0x5937c7]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::_mfi::mf4<void, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int>::operator()(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group*, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int) const at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:506) [0x56ed04]
PassengerHelperAgent(void boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner> >, boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned int> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf4<void, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf4<void, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind.hpp:525) [0x56739c]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf4<void, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner> >, boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned int> > >::operator()() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:21) [0x55e65b]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf4<void, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group>, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner>, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options, unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner> >, boost::_bi::value<Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned int> > >, void>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/function/function_template.hpp:154) [0x55516a]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::function0<void>::operator()() const at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/function/function_template.hpp:768) [0x50e05d]
PassengerHelperAgent(oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_main(boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/oxt/dynamic_thread_group.hpp:109) [0x4b52fa]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, oxt::dynamic_thread_group, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*>::operator()(oxt::dynamic_thread_group*, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*) const at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:281) [0x56d19c]
PassengerHelperAgent(void boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, oxt::dynamic_thread_group, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, oxt::dynamic_thread_group, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind.hpp:393) [0x564444]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, oxt::dynamic_thread_group, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*> > >::operator()() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:21) [0x55b78d]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, oxt::dynamic_thread_group, boost::function<void ()()>&, oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<oxt::dynamic_thread_group::thread_handle*> > >, void>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/function/function_template.hpp:154) [0x550eb7]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::function0<void>::operator()() const at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/function/function_template.hpp:768) [0x50e05d]
PassengerHelperAgent(oxt::thread::thread_main(boost::function<void ()()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/oxt/implementation.cpp:351) [0x5da92a]
PassengerHelperAgent(void boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > >::operator()<void (*)(boost::function<void ()()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, void (*&)(boost::function<void ()()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list0&, int) at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313) [0x577ace]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::function<void ()()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > > >::operator()() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:21) [0x577365]
PassengerHelperAgent(boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::function<void ()()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > > > >::run() at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:118) [0x5765a8]
PassengerHelperAgent(thread_proxy at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/ext/boost/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:164) [0x5d5e75]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(?? at ??:0; +0x79d1) [0x7fac7a7489d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(?? at ??:0; clone+0x6d) [0x7fac79aedb6d]
--------------------------------------
[ pid=10486 ] Dumping additional diagnostical information...
--------------------------------------
### Request handler state
1 clients:
  Client 20:
    host                        = legion.polybian.com
    uri                         = /
    connected at                = 2014-03-05 16:24:35 (0 sec ago)
    state                       = CHECKING_OUT_SESSION
    session                     = NULL
    requestBodyIsBuffered       = false
    contentLength               = -1
    clientBodyAlreadyRead       = 0
    clientInput                 = 0x7fac58001490 fd=20, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0
    clientInput started         = false
    clientBodyBuffer started    = false
    clientBodyBuffer reachedEnd = false
    clientOutputPipe started    = true
    clientOutputPipe reachedEnd = false
    clientOutputWatcher active  = false
    appInput                    = 0x7fac580037a0 fd=-1, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=1, error=0
    appInput started            = false
    appInput reachedEnd         = false
    responseHeaderSeen          = false
    useUnionStation             = false

### Pool state (simple)
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs#default:
  App root: /var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs
  (spawning 1 new process...)
  Requests in queue: 1


### Pool state (XML)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1" ?>
<info version="2"><process_count>0</process_count><max>6</max><capacity_used>1</capacity_used><get_wait_list_size>0</get_wait_list_size><get_wait_list></get_wait_list><supergroups><supergroup><name>/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs</name><state>READY</state><get_wait_list_size>0</get_wait_list_size><capacity_used>1</capacity_used><secret>z4Gzfny1sNuFrt8nhUmVBJdIjPZjpwoQrid8DRHuby9</secret><group default="true"><name>/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs&#35;default</name><component_name>default</component_name><app_root>/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs</app_root><app_type>rack</app_type><environment>production</environment><enabled_process_count>0</enabled_process_count><disabling_process_count>0</disabling_process_count><disabled_process_count>0</disabled_process_count><capacity_used>1</capacity_used><get_wait_list_size>1</get_wait_list_size><disable_wait_list_size>0</disable_wait_list_size><processes_being_spawned>1</processes_being_spawned><spawning/><secret>ve2ivZ7iYHqOMvDYxETlxXq7Z9rmdAiOG0GYaKlt02H</secret><life_status>ALIVE</life_status><options><app_root>/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs</app_root><app_group_name>/var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs</app_group_name><app_type>rack</app_type><start_command>/usr/local/bin/ruby&#9;/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb</start_command><startup_file>config.ru</startup_file><process_title>Passenger RackApp</process_title><log_level>0</log_level><start_timeout>90000</start_timeout><environment>production</environment><base_uri>/</base_uri><spawn_method>smart</spawn_method><default_user>nobody</default_user><default_group>nobody</default_group><ruby>/usr/local/bin/ruby</ruby><python>python</python><nodejs>node</nodejs><logging_agent_address>unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7867/generation-1/logging</logging_agent_address><logging_agent_username>logging</logging_agent_username><logging_agent_password>A81cKmeoE15ivO41jIKP2WzQyEREeicphl6JD8fZYQucvjMNcuHml1cIvOfft2UQ</logging_agent_password><debugger>false</debugger><analytics>false</analytics><group_secret>ve2ivZ7iYHqOMvDYxETlxXq7Z9rmdAiOG0GYaKlt02H</group_secret><min_processes>1</min_processes><max_processes>0</max_processes><max_preloader_idle_time>-1</max_preloader_idle_time><max_out_of_band_work_instances>1</max_out_of_band_work_instances></options><processes></processes></group></supergroup></supergroups></info>

### Backtraces
Thread 'Main thread' (0x7fac7ab6e720, LWP 10486):
     in 'void Server::mainLoop()' (Main.cpp:569)

Thread 'MultiLibeio dispatcher' (0x7fac7ab6c700, LWP 10486):
     (empty)

Thread 'Pool analytics collector' (0x7fac7ab5b700, LWP 10486):
     in 'static void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Pool::collectAnalytics(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::PoolPtr)' (Pool.h:746)

Thread 'Pool garbage collector' (0x7fac7ab1a700, LWP 10486):
     in 'static void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Pool::garbageCollect(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::PoolPtr)' (Pool.h:613)

Thread 'MessageServer thread' (0x7fac7aad9700, LWP 10486):
     in 'void Passenger::MessageServer::mainLoop()' (MessageServer.h:580)

Thread 'Pool event loop' (0x7fac79003700, LWP 10486):
     (empty)

Thread 'Request event loop' (0x7fac63fff700, LWP 10486):
     (empty)

Thread 'Group process spawner: /var/www/vhosts/legion.polybian.com/httpdocs#default' (0x7fac7aa77700, LWP 10776):
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:455)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:590)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:752)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:804)

Thread 'Background I/O capturer' (0x7fac7a9f5700, LWP 10777):
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturer::capture()' (Spawner.h:133)

--------------------------------------
[ pid=10486 ] Open files and file descriptors:
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() sysfs file system /sys
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() devpts file system /dev/pts
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /dev/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() usbfs file system /proc/bus/usb
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext4 file system /boot
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() binfmt_misc file system /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
Passenger 10486 root  cwd       DIR  253,0     4096       2 /
Passenger 10486 root  rtd       DIR  253,0     4096       2 /
Passenger 10486 root  txt       REG  253,0 13556835 1447527 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0    65928 1181690 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0  1921216 1181674 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0    90880 1179650 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0   596264 1181682 /lib64/libm-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0   987096  918660 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0    43832 1181702 /lib64/librt-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0   142640 1181698 /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root  mem       REG  253,0   154520 1181667 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
Passenger 10486 root    0r      CHR    1,3      0t0    3788 /dev/null
Passenger 10486 root    1w     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1358298 pipe
Passenger 10486 root    2w     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1358298 pipe
Passenger 10486 root    3u     sock    0,6      0t0 1357424 can't identify protocol
Passenger 10486 root    5w     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1358298 pipe
Passenger 10486 root    8u  unknown                         [eventfd] (stat: Permission denied)
Passenger 10486 root    9u  unknown                         [eventpoll] (stat: Permission denied)
Passenger 10486 root   10u  unknown                         [eventfd] (stat: Permission denied)
Passenger 10486 root   11u  unknown                         [eventpoll] (stat: Permission denied)
Passenger 10486 root   12u  unknown                         [eventfd] (stat: Permission denied)
Passenger 10486 root   13r     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1357450 pipe
Passenger 10486 root   14w     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1357450 pipe
Passenger 10486 root   15u     sock    0,6      0t0 1357451 can't identify protocol
Passenger 10486 root   16u     sock    0,6      0t0 1357453 can't identify protocol
Passenger 10486 root   17r      CHR    1,9      0t0    3793 /dev/urandom
Passenger 10486 root   18r      CHR    1,9      0t0    3793 /dev/urandom
Passenger 10486 root   20u     sock    0,6      0t0 1358258 can't identify protocol
Passenger 10486 root   22u     sock    0,6      0t0 1358264 can't identify protocol
Passenger 10486 root   23r     FIFO    0,8      0t0 1358265 pipe
--------------------------------------
[ pid=10486 ] Dumping a more detailed backtrace with crash-watch...
Found gdb at: /usr/bin/gdb
Current thread () backtrace:
    No stack.

All thread backtraces:

[Wed Mar 05 16:24:36 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.117] Premature end of script headers:
[ 2014-03-05 16:24:36.4266 8892/7f91f6e96700 agents/Watchdog/AgentWatcher.cpp:96 ]: Phusion Passenger helper agent (pid=10486) crashed with signal SIGSEGV, restarting it...
[ 2014-03-05 16:24:36.4386 10813/7fdbc7dcd720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:643 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7867/generation-1/request
```

I suspect that the problem lies either in:

```
[ pid=10486, timestamp=1394054675 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4, randomSeed=1394054282
```

or in:

```
[Wed Mar 05 16:24:36 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.117] Premature end of script headers:
```

But I've been unable to find a solution based on searching for these.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you make sure your permissions are right on project dir? that apache user has r_x access to it?

Comment: Double checked that and no dice.

Comment: I would recommend using a different version of passenger gem (maybe there is an update out?) and reinstalling apache module (and reconfigure conf file to point to new path for the module)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... got it up and running. Mostly thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712190/1313409).

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

this got it up and running but then follow the update to ensure that you don't run into this again after a reboot of the server

@luriG you were half correct. After the above fix I was getting a "doesn't have permission" for the user. I had to chmod the directory to *765* to get Passenger/Apache to see it. Thanks for your help